# Django rounding decimal number to n decimal places based on another column

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I am using PostgreSQL and Django with the following model

```
class Example(model.Model):
    num = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)
    round_to= models.IntegerField()
```

What I would like to achieve is that:

```
Example.objects.annotate(rounded = Round(F('num'),F('round_to'))
```

But it seems that `Round` function only allow me to round to integer. According to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#round

Comment: Which DB are you using? If you want to perform the rounding at the DB level there are DB functions you can call

Comment: PostgreSQL, how do I call the DB functions? Cus it seems that Django's DB round function only allows rounding to integer @Iain Shelvington

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in `Round` function only rounds to the nearest integer. If you are using postgres you can add your own database function to call `ROUND()` by subclassing [`Func`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) and use it in your queries

```
from django.db.models import Func

class RoundWithPlaces(Func):
    function = 'ROUND'

Example.objects.annotate(rounded=RoundWithPlaces(F('num'), F('round_to')))
```

Answer (score 7):

This is resolved in Django 4.

The new precision argument of the `Round()` database function allows specifying the number of decimal places after rounding. [Release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#models).

```
from django.db.models.functions import Round

Example.objects.annotate(rounded=Round(F('num'), precision=F('round_to'))
```